# Remove currencies from Zend

Tags: currency

I would like to remove all currencies in Magento and just leave a few manually added ones. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to remove available currencies from the backend?

Comment: You mean from the system configuration ?

Comment: If you just want to remove the $, €, etc. signs I think the easiest way is to change the price.phtml...

Answer (score 1):

The list of currencies come from this method 
`Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Currency::toOptionArray`. This is the source model for the currency list.
Actually it comes from `Mage_Core_Model_Locale::getOptionCurrencies` and we can go deeper if you want until we reach some Zend class but there is no need for that.
You can just override the method I mentioned and make it return only the list of currencies you want as an array of arrays. Each element in the main array should look like this

```
array(
    'label' => 'Currency label',
    'value' => 'CODE',
);
```

You can also change the source model for the currency multiselect to one of yours, but it takes more code to do it.